# Alter to varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to alter a table from int to varchar using

```
ALTER TABLE shares
ALTER COLUMN link VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

Currently getting the error message

```
  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following query :

```
ALTER TABLE shares MODIFY COLUMN link VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Glad, it helped you

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MySQL, then the syntax should be:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

so:

```
ALTER TABLE shares MODIFY COLUMN link VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

The syntax you were using was for SQL Server.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `shares`
MODIFY COLUMN `link` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's work only if the old table definition have data that will be compatible with the new definition of the column